# Django How to deploy image from database?

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

My project is the website which is moderated by a editor with admin laws (by the admin panel). He can add images for articles. Images are stored in the database.

My problem is that I cant access images from the database in my website. They aren't displaying at all.

Here is my structure of folders:

[folders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1C9fr.png)

in my project there are two apps: accounts and blog. For purpose of order i want to store images inside "blog" app in the folders like in the image.

Here is my code:

Models.py:

```
class Reviews(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    game_title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    content = models.CharField(max_length=10000)
    game_rating = models.DecimalField(max_digits=2, decimal_places=1)
    game_user_rating = models.DecimalField(max_digits=2, decimal_places=1)
    date_of_publishing = models.DateField()

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.game_title}"

class ReviewsMiniaturesImages(models.Model):
    miniature_image = models.ImageField(upload_to="blog/static/reviews_miniatures_images/")
    description = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    review = models.ForeignKey(Reviews, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Template:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}
{% for review in reviews %}
<div class="h-100 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
  <div class="card" style="width: 60rem;">
    <img src="{% static  review.reviewsminiaturesimages_set.get.miniature_image %}" class="card-img-top"
         alt="{{ review.reviewsminiaturesimages_set.get.description }}}}">
    <div class="card-body">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <h5 class="card-title">{{review.game_title}}</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="col-7 d-flex justify-content-center">
          <h4 class="card-title">{{review.title}}</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="col d-flex justify-content-end">
          <h5 class="card-title">{{review.date_of_publishing}}</h5>
        </div>
      </div>
      <p class="card-text">{{review.description}}</p>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <a href="{% url 'reviews-detail' review.id %}" class="btn btn-primary">To review</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col d-flex justify-content-end">
          <form action="" method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Add 'To Read'">
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

views.py

```
class ReviewsListView(ListView):
    model = Reviews
    queryset = Reviews.objects.order_by("date_of_publishing")
    context_object_name = "reviews"
    template_name = "reviews.html"
```

settings.py

```
# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = "static/"
```

In this case the path for the image is not correct. It can be seen in this image:
[image path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SHJUf.png)

What can I do to maintain the structure of my folders ( it is implicating that upload to attribute in database will be the same) and serve static images? Maybe I should serve them as media images? Which option is better and how to achieve displaying image after upload

I tried to read documentation and tried to serve files with static or without static in the template. It doesnt display in both conditions.

EDITED:

Regarding the answer below I tried otherwise with media folder:

models.py:

```
   class ReviewsMiniaturesImages(models.Model):
    miniature_image = models.ImageField(upload_to="blog/media/reviews_miniatures_images/")
    description = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    game_title = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.game_title} {self.description}"


class Reviews(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    game_title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    content = models.CharField(max_length=10000)
    game_rating = models.DecimalField(max_digits=2, decimal_places=1)
    game_user_rating = models.DecimalField(max_digits=2, decimal_places=1)
    date_of_publishing = models.DateField()
    review_minature_image = models.ForeignKey(ReviewsMiniaturesImages, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.game_title}"
```

settings.py:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = "/blog/media/reviews_miniatures_images/"
```

template:

```
 <img src="{{ review.review_minature_image.miniature_image }}" class="card-img-top"
     alt="{{ review.review_minature_image.description }}">
```

it doesnt work too

Comment: Add the definition for `Reviews`

Comment: Reviews added from models.py

Answer (score 0):

There is your problem. You are trying to access `ReviewsMiniaturesImages` instances related to `Reviews` using a [`RelatedManager`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/relations/#django.db.models.fields.related.RelatedManager) but [you are doing it wrong](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/relations/#django.db.models.fields.related.RelatedManager).

```html
<img src="{% static  review.reviewsminiaturesimages_set.get.miniature_image %}" class="card-img-top"
         alt="{{ review.reviewsminiaturesimages_set.get.description }}}}">
```

If you want to achieve what you are doing in your templates very easily and without much changes to your code base, consider creating a [Many to One](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/#many-to-one-relationships) relationship in the `Reviews` class instead. That way a `ReviewsMiniaturesImages` instance can be accessed from a `Reviews` instance.
Consider something like this:

```py
class Reviews(models.Model):
    ••• #other fields
    reviews_miniatures_image = models.ForeignKey(“ReviewsMiniaturesImages”, on_delete=models.CASCADE) # “ReviewsMiniaturesImages” added lazily.
```

Now something like this should work:

```html
<img src="{{ review.reviews_miniatures_image.miniature_image }}" class="card-img-top"
         alt="{{ review.reviews_miniatures_image.description }}">
```

Consider getting rid of this `review` attribute in `ReviewsMiniaturesImages`:

```py
class ReviewsMiniaturesImages(models.Model):
    •••
    review = models.ForeignKey(Reviews, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Make sure you are handling these Image (Media) Files [properly](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#media-root). [See managing user-uploaded files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/files/#managing-files).

Comment: hiperlink under "See managing user-uploaded files" doesnt work. Could You verify it?

Comment: It does work. Try it once more. It shows how Django manages media files for you including the media path, media root and file storage.

Comment: I changed my code to media root way. But it doesnt work. What am I doing wrong?